# Getting link or file from uploads folder of ArcGIS Server feature service?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-rest-api, feature-service

I have succeeded in adding a file to arcgis server with the upload method of a feature service on arcgis server. But i can't see how to download what i have uploaded to.

How can I have a link (like the printTask button) or get the file ?

Answer (score 1):

here is an example (in which 3549 is an ObjectID of a particular feature within the service)

http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/SF311/FeatureServer/0/3549/attachments

in our JavaScript API, you can use FeatureLayer.[queryattachmentinfos()](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#queryattachmentinfos) to identify a url like this on the fly.

Comment: i would like to retrive the file uploaded at this url : http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/SF311/FeatureServer/uploads/upload

Comment: thanks for the clarification.  to be honest, i'm not exactly sure why that particular utility is present in FeatureServer.  For Geoprocessing Services it can be utilized to push a file which will afterward be used as an input parameter when running the tool, but in neither case is a 'download' option exposed.  http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Upload/02r3000000nw000000/